# Simple Form- control width of label and input (with bootstrap)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I am using Simple_form and Bootstrap.

I would like to use a horizontal wrapper, but I need to make the label wider and the input narrower. I would like to do this with bootstrap 4 vs custom css.

The label and input should be on the same line (inline), and right aligned.

col-md-8 for label and col-md-4 for input.  How do I do that?

```
 <%= f.input :role, :wrapper =>:horizontal_range, input_wrapper_html: { class: "col-md-4"}, label_wrapper_html: {class: "col-md-8"} %>
```

EDIT: I should add that the f.input :role is contained within a

```
<div class='row'>
  <div class='col-md-6"> 
      f.input :role 
  </div>
</div>
```

Second,

I need to add a % at the end of my input. However, it does not seem to work.

```
 <%= f.input :pct_of_car , append: "%",  :wrapper =>:horizontal_range %>
```

However, this does not seem to work.  What is wrong with my syntax?

Third, how would one modify the vertical collection_inline to have 2 or 3 columns?

```
  # vertical input for inline radio buttons and check boxes
  config.wrappers :bs_vertical_collection_inline, item_wrapper_class: 'form-check form-check-inline', tag: 'fieldset', class: 'form-group', error_class: 'form-group-invalid', valid_class: 'form-group-valid' do |b|
    b.use :html5
    b.optional :readonly
    b.wrapper :legend_tag, tag: 'legend', class: 'col-form-label pt-0' do |ba|
      ba.use :label_text
    end
    b.use :input, class: 'form-check-input', error_class: 'is-invalid', valid_class: 'is-valid'
    b.use :full_error, wrap_with: { tag: 'div', class: 'invalid-feedback d-block' }
    b.use :hint, wrap_with: { tag: 'small', class: 'form-text text-muted' }
  end
```

Currently all the checkboxes are listed inline and have no structure. I need to list the choices in 2 or 3 columns so that they are easier to read. This is also a long list, so may need to wrap the choices in a scroll box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set class for `input` and `label`, please use `input_html` and `label_html`:

```
<%= f.input :role, :wrapper => :horizontal_range, input_html: { class: "col-md-4"}, label_html: {class: "col-md-8"} %>
```

Regarding the second issue - if you are not using hints, probably the easiest solution would be to do it like this:

```
<%= f.input :pct_of_car , hint: "%",  :wrapper =>:horizontal_range %>
```

Then, you can style it by adding a custom class to the hint with `hint_html` option (similar to `input_html` and `label_html`).

#### Update

A better solution for adding custom text is to use block for the input:

```
<%= f.input(:role, :wrapper => :horizontal_range, label_html: {class: "col-md-8"}) do %>
  <div class='col-md-4'>
    <%= f.input(:role, components: [:input], :wrapper => false, label: false) %>
    <span>%</span>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Thanks to that, your label has `col-md-8` class, and input with your text are wrapped in a div with `col-md-4` class.

Comment: I need the label and input to be all on the same line (all inline). for some reason your method drops the input to next line, any ideas? I

Comment: I guess it is because of the `:horizontal_range` structure. Can you please add it to the question?

Comment: @user2012677 by `:horizontal_range` I meant the code for the wrapper, it is probably defined in `config/initializers/simple_form.rb` :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to define your own custom wrapper or modify the default ones.

#### First, ensure you have the default wrappers in your repository.

Run `rails g simple_form:install --bootstrap` if you can not locate `app/initializers/simple_form_bootstrap.rb`.

#### Second, locate the Bootstrap grid classes in this initializer.  For a horizontal form, they are found in a block that looks like this:

```
config.wrappers :horizontal_form, tag: 'div', class: 'form-group', error_class: 'has-error' do |b|
    b.use :html5
    b.use :placeholder
    b.optional :maxlength
    b.optional :minlength
    b.optional :pattern
    b.optional :min_max
    b.optional :readonly
    b.use :label, class: 'col-sm-3 control-label'

    b.wrapper tag: 'div', class: 'col-sm-9' do |ba|
      ba.use :input, class: 'form-control'
      ba.use :error, wrap_with: { tag: 'span', class: 'help-block' }
      ba.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: 'p', class: 'help-block' }
    end
  end
```

#### Third, change the wrapper!

In this snippet, change `col-sm-9` to `col-sm-8`.
Also Change `col-sm-3` to `col-sm-4`.

#### Finishing up

Save. Restart your Rails server.  Now all forms will have 33% width labels, and 66% width inputs.

If you don't want to apply this globally, pass the `wrapper: :my_wrapper` option to any `input` and create a new custom wrapper that does what you'd like it to do.

Gotta love SimpleForm!